# Git private repository

Tags: git, composer-php

When I use this

```php
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "name/vendor",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "url": "git@github.com:name/vendor.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

my `autoload_psr4.php` file is not generated with path I declare in my repository, but when I use the following configuration, it works ok.

```php
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "git@github.com:name/vendor.git"
}
```

I want to know why the first configuration generates the composer autoload files correctly, but the second configuration does not.

Edit 2:

Running `composer update` with the first configuration results in the following autoloads:

```php
return array(
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/monolog-bundle'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/assetic-bundle'),
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

When I changed to the second configuration, the autoload has:

```php
return array(
    'skowronline\\TaskBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/skowronline/taskbundle'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\MonologBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/monolog-bundle'),
    'Symfony\\Bundle\\AsseticBundle\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/assetic-bundle'),
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
);
```

I hope this is more clear.

**Solution**:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories

> Repository declarations of dependencies' composer.jsons are ignored.

Comment: it's not really clear, what you're asking

Comment: Where's your question? This 'question' isn't very clear, quite surprising for a user with more than 1,000 reputation!

Comment: @cybermonkey checkout now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the first configuration with type `package`, you are telling composer to **override** the `composer.json` in `git@github.com:name/vendor.git`. The autoload parameter will never be read. You can fix this by doing:

```json
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "name/vendor",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "url": "git@github.com:name/vendor.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "master"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {<your autoload config>}
        }
    }
}
```

When you use the second configuration, all you are doing is telling composer to look in `git@github.com:name/vendor.git` before downloading from packagist. In this case, composer will read the `composer.json` from the repository including the autoload settings.

**The second configuration is the preferred way.** When you use a `package` declaration like in your first example, you are overriding the package author's original configuration. Don't do this unless you have a good reason.

Comment: thanks for anwser, didnt know why this should be used